# Generators of an ideal that form a regular sequence

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian $k$-algebra which is an integral domain and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, $I:=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n \rangle$
with $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in R$ a [regular sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence).

Assume that $b_1,\ldots,b_m \in R$ also generate $I$, namely:
$I=\langle b_1,\ldots,b_m \rangle$.

> When $b_1,\ldots,b_m$ is a regular sequence? Probably not always?

Perhaps the following questions are relevant: [i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170405/ideals-generated-by-regular-sequences-are-generated-by-regular-sequences-in-any) and [ii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836854/computing-a-regular-sequence-of-generators-for-an-ideal).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: The question is vague. It is better to ask the case you are most interested in. The answer to your second question is "No, not always." Also no to the first one unless $m = n$.

Comment: @Youngsu, thank you for your comment. I am interested in polynomial rings over fields, $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where $n \geq 2$ ($k[x]$ is a PID, so there is no much to ask). Please, could you elaborate on "Also no to the first one unless $m=n$"? Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707098/existence-of-a-finite-length-maximal-regular-sequence

Comment: @Youngsu, please, in particular, in $k[x,y]$, if we know that $I=\langle u,v \rangle= \langle a,b,c,d \rangle$, with $u,v$ regular, can we pick two of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and get a regular sequence? (which will not necessarily generate all $I$).

Comment: If $I=(x,y)$ and $a=(xy+1)x$, $b=(xy+1)y$, $c=xy$, $d=0$, then no two of these form a regular sequence.

Comment: @user26857, nice, thanks. What if $abcd \neq 0$? Or what if every two of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are algebraically independent over $k$?

Comment: Similarly one can construct an example with none of the generators equal to zero.

Comment: The idea is to choose these generators such that the gcd of any two of them is not 1. This is what I did in the example above.

Comment: @user26857, thank you for the clarification.